# operator overloading for __truediv__ in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, overloading, operator-keyword

I am trying to overload the division operator in python.

```
class Fraction:
    def __init__(self,top,bottom):
        def gcd(m, n):
            while m % n != 0:
                old_m = m
                old_n = n
                m = old_n
                n = old_m % old_n
            return n
        common = gcd(top,bottom)
        self.num = top/common
        self.den = bottom/common
    def __str__ (self):
        return str(self.num) + "/" + str(self.den)
    def get_num(self):
        return self.num
    def get_den(self):
        return self.den
    def __add__(self, other_fraction):
        new_num = self.num * other_fraction.den + self.den * other_fraction.num
        new_den = self.den * other_fraction.den
        return Fraction(new_num, new_den)
    def __sub__(self, other_fraction):
        new_num = self.num * other_fraction.den - self.den * other_fraction.num
        new_den = self.den * other_fraction.den
        return Fraction(new_num, new_den)
    def __mul__ (self, other_fraction):
        new_num = self.num * other_fraction.num
        new_den = self.den * other_fraction.den
        return Fraction(new_num, new_den)
    def __truediv__(self, other_fraction):
        new_num = self.num * other_fraction.den
        new_den = self.den * other_fraction.num
        return Fraction(new_num, new_den)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        first_num = self.num * other.den    
        second_num = other.num * self.den
        return first_num == second_num
    
a = Fraction(10,20)
b = Fraction(30,20)
print a
print "numerator is",a.get_num()
print "denominator is",a.get_den()
print "equality is",(a==b)
print "sum is",(a+b)
print "difference is",(a-b)
print "product is",(a*b)
print "division is",(a/b)
```

But I get an error at `__truediv__`:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'instance' and
> 'instance'

What is wrong with the code?

Comment: `from fraction import Fraction`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `object.__truediv__()` special method is *only* used with the `/` operator and then only if you have switched the Python compiler to use true division with:

```
from __future__ import division
```

If you did not use that import, the `/` operator calls the [`object.__div__()` special method](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__div__) if present.

The `//` operator on the other hand calls the [`object.__floordiv__()` special method](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__floordiv__), which you did not implement.

Answer (score 26):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/datamodel.html#object.__truediv__):

> ```
> object.__div__(self, other) 
> object.__truediv__(self, other)
> ```
>
> The division operator (/) is implemented by these methods. The
>   `__truediv__()` method is used when `__future__.division` is in effect, otherwise `__div__()` is used. If only one of these two methods is
>   defined, the object will not support division in the alternate
>   context; TypeError will be raised instead.

And [here](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#future):

> A future statement is a directive to the compiler that a particular
>   [python program] should be compiled using syntax or semantics that will be
>   available in a ... future release of Python. The future
>   statement is intended to ease migration to future versions of Python
>   that introduce incompatible changes to the language. It allows use of
>   the new features before the release in which the
>   feature becomes standard.
>
> ```
> future_statement: from __future__ import feature
> ```
>
> The features recognized by Python 2.x are unicode_literals,
>   print_function, absolute_import, division, generators, nested_scopes
>   and with_statement

Now, some tests:

```
~$ python2.7
Python 2.7.6 (v2.7.6:3a1db0d2747e, Nov 10 2013, 00:42:54) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 3/2
1
>>> exit()

~$ python3.2
Python 3.2.3 (v3.2.3:3d0686d90f55, Apr 10 2012, 11:25:50) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 3/2
1.5
```

So, you see, the effect of the `/` operator changed in python 3.x. You can see that in the example below, as well:

```
class Dog(object):
    def __div__(self, other):
        print("__div__ called")
    def __truediv__(self, other):
        print("__truediv__ called")


Dog() / Dog()

--output:--
~/python_programs$ python2.7 myprog.py 
__div__ called

~/python_programs$ python3.4 myprog.py
__truediv__ called
```

Because `__truediv__` is not called by the `/` operator in python 2.x, overriding `__truediv__` in python 2.x has no effect.

```
PEP 238 - PEP 238 -- Changing the Division Operator

We propose the following transitional measures:

    - Classic division will remain the default in the Python 2.x
      series; true division will be standard in Python 3.0.

    - The // operator will be available to request floor[, i.e. integer,] 
      division unambiguously.

    - The future division statement, spelled "from __future__ import
      division", will change the / operator to mean true division
      throughout the [program]
```

Now, look what happens here:

```
from __future__ import division

class Dog(object):
    def __div__(self, other):
        print("__div__ called")
    def __truediv__(self, other):
        print("__truediv__ called")


Dog() / Dog()

--output:--
~/python_programs$ python2.7 myprog.py 
__truediv__ called

~/python_programs$ python3.4 myprog.py
__truediv__ called
```

Now, you get the python3.x effect for the `/` operator in python 2.x.  So, now you can override `__truediv__` to make the `/` operator do what you want.

Note that if you want integer division in python 3.x, i.e. `3/2 => 1`, then you have to use the `//` operator, which is implemented by `__floordiv__`.  Likewise, if you do `from __future__ import division` in python 2.x, then to get integer division, you have to use the `//` operator; and if you want to override the `//` operator in a class, you need to implement `__floordiv__`.