# Trying to Understand This Line in the Code

Tags: python, class, oop

I'm kinda new to Python, and just got into Object Oriented. I think I understand the basic but this line of code has really got me confused.

Here's the entire piece:

```
class SpecialString:
    def __init__(self, cont):
        self.cont = cont

    def __truediv__(self, other):
        line = "=" * len(other.cont)
        return "\n".join([self.cont, line, other.cont])

spam = SpecialString("spam")
hello = SpecialString("Hello world!")
print(spam / hello)
```

I'm talking about the this one:

```
line = "=" * len(other.cont)
```

I don't get what 'other.cont' mean. How can an object be an attribute of **another** object? Or is 'cont' just being applied on 'other'?

Comment: There's no problem with having an object as an attribute of another object, but in this case it is simply referring to a different objects `.cont` attribute

Comment: You're passing other, which is a function, and it has an attribute called other.cont. So you're referencing an attribute in this case that is in the other function. Which is okay in Python.

Comment: @SimeonIkudabo _You're passing other, which is a function_ Why is other necessarily a function?

Comment: @SimeonIkudabo `other` isn't a function. He's passing `hello` as `other`, and `hello` is an instance of `SpecialString`.

Comment: The OP may have an indentation error, but other seems to be the __init__ method of the class in this scenario, with the attribute cont

Comment: `other` is clearly just an object.  It's an argument.  Functions don't have attributes, and `other.cont` is the `cont` attribute of the object defined as `other`

Comment: Likely, `other` is an instance of the `SpecialString` class, but there's no proof to say that definitively.

Comment: It may help to think about code you write at the top level, when you aren't thinking about objects, like `os.listdir()` or `mylist.sort()` or `print(spam.eggs)`. You're doing the exact same thing with `other.cont` here. The only difference is that `other` happens to be a function parameter rather than a global variable, and that doesn't make any difference. You can write `def revsort(mylist): mylist.sort(reversed=True)`, right?

Comment: @ChootsMagoots Methods/Functions have attributes. cont is an attribute in the __init__ method of the class. An attribute is a variable that belongs to a method or function. So I don't think what you're saying is correct.

Comment: @SimeonIkudabo Yes, there's an indentation error in pasting here, but even with that error, there's no way `other` could be the `__init__` function.

Comment: @ChootsMagoots Yes there is proof: `print(spam / hello)` is calling `spam.__truediv__(hello)`, and `hello` is an instance of `SpecialString`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ***truediv**()* special method is only used with the / operator.

Below is how i can breakdown the ***truediv***. This is basically known as operator overloading.

```
def __truediv__(self, SpecialString("Hello world!")):
    #line = "=" * len(other.cont)
    line = "=" * len(SpecialString("Hello world!").cont)

    #return "\n".join([self.cont, line, other.cont])
    return "\n".join([SpecialString("spam").cont, line, SpecialString("Hello world!").cont])
```

Other here is the 2nd class instance that is being passed.

There is a question in SO which answers operator overloading of **truediv**()in detail. You can check it here: [operator overloading for __truediv__ in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29155829/operator-overloading-for-truediv-in-python)

Comment: Follow up question, what good is `.cont` then? It seems like `line` is just there to set the number of `=`, whay would you need `.cont` for that? Is that the string?

Comment: The `.cont` is being used for two purposes right now. To set `=` count and finally, you are printing the values using the `.cont` variable.

Answer (score 0):

The method expects two object instances as parameters, `self` and `other`. The code doesn't care as such which class `other` belongs to, as long as it has a `cont` attribute, too, which has a length. But the division method commonly takes two objects of the same type.

(When an object of a different type behaves the same as yours, that's called *polymorphism.* This isn't crucial to understand at this point, but you've probably come across the concept.)